# Dialog with list serialization error (bot framework)

Tags: list, serialization, dialog, botframework

I have the following error when I try to compile my code:

Error CA2235: Field contacts is a member of type NamesDialog which is serializable but is of type System.Collections.Generic.List which is not serializable

code:

```
[Serializable]
public class Contact
{
    public Contact(string sip, string name, int score)
    {
        this.Sip = sip;
        this.Name = name;
        this.score= score;
    }

    public string Sip { get; }

    public string Name { get; }

    public int score{ get; }
}

[Serializable]
public class NamesDialog : IDialog<Contact>
{
    private readonly List<Contact> contacts;

    public NamesDialog(List<Contact> contacts)
    {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    // need to update.
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        something...
    }
}
```

If anyone knows anything please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried embedding the class Contact inside your dialog (Or simply making it a separate file)? When you do this remove `[serializable]`

Comment: At the moment those classes are in separate files. Embedding Contact in Dialog can solve it, but I don't think this is the correct way to do this. Do you have maybe other ideas? thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your error and can't seem to do so...one thing I noticed when I included your code in a bot project is that the line `public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)` causes an error; it should be `public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)`

Comment: I am also unable to repro as well